# Docker buildkit experimental stopped working

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm using `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental` in my Dockerfile, I use it to mount ssh but for some reason it stopped working.

I have the env `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` and already tried with `DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled` but nothing changed.

```
2 transferring context: 69B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 402B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental
#3 ERROR: docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental not found
------
 > resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental:
------
docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental not found
```

There's the output and the problem.

Best regards

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or anything else that would intercept connections to the internet?

Comment: @BMitch no, it was some kind of bug. Forcing pull done it right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed by forcing pull.

```
docker pull docker/dockerfile:experimental
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. What did this do?